# how to send an image and additional data in ASP.NET WebAPI with Postman?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to send an **image and additional data**, for example, `userId` to my API. But, these are two different types.

How to send an image and some additional data in Postman?

Answer (score 1):

First, create an action which receives `IFormData` and a `string` caption ( you can put them in a separate class if you want ) :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormFile image, string caption)
    {
        // Save image here
        return Ok(caption);
    }
}
```

and with Postman, simply submit a form-data request like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For small files (eg up to 200 to 300 MB) you can use the following 2 tutorials to tell you the trick.

[1](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/612cf2d1-5b3d-40eb-a5ff-924005955a62.aspx) | [2](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/)

But if your file is too large (eg 500 megabytes up to several gigabytes)
Better use the Chunk method (crushing the bulk file into smaller pieces and then uploading these pieces and eventually stacking them to the server)

The following table has implemented this feature well
To do this, you need to write both the server-side of the code and the client-side of the plugin to do the chunking work (albeit handy but easier with the plugin) such as [this](https://github.com/edsoncunha/chunked-file-upload-csharp)  Resumable.js plugin

Note: Be sure to run the program on Kestrel to run it, otherwise it has restrictions in IISExpress mode.

---

refrence : [DotNetZoom](https://t.me/DotNetZoom/877) Channle in Telegram